# Crawl stop after item count reached 2million+ in web application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search, crawling, threshold

I am using SharePoint 2013 foundation in dev environment. Suddenly I found that the crawl is stopped. The error message is showing

> The crawl item threshold is exceeded.

I delete more than 500K documents to reduce the count less than 2M but still, it crawl is not started!

How to start crawl again!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the index and starting a full crawl?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft increase the threshold limit to 10 million but you have to apply June 2016 CU.

> For SharePoint Foundation 2013, the maximum number of indexed items is
>   2 million items per index partition. For SharePoint Foundation 2013,
>   the maximum number of indexed items is 2 million items per index
>   partition, before applying the **June 2016 Public Update**. The June
>   2016 Public Update, increases this limit to **10 million items per
>   index partition.**

here is the KB: [June 14, 2016, update for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB3115168)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115168/june-14--2016--update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb3115168)

Or you can add another index partition to the search.

Comment: the link says it support SharePoint 2013 SP1,  my concern is, will this KB is supported to Sharepoint foundation as well !